# Passing a dictionary value to and fro in TCL

Tags: dictionary, tcl, procedure

I am trying to write a script which uses a **dictionary** value to store some data. I am then using the same dictionary value to a **procedure** for further processing. It looks something like this :

```
proc testProc {a} {
   some statements ...
   dict incr a key2 1
}

set dummy [dict create]
dict incr dummy key1 1
testProc $dummy 

puts "[dict get $dummy]"
```

I expected to get output as :

> key1 1 key2 1

Instead I got :

> key1 1

If I want my output first one , then how should i do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`testProc` updates a *copy* of the dict. You can either return the modified one and save it:

```
proc testProc {a} {
    # some statements ...
    dict incr a key2 1
    return $a
}

set dummy [dict create]
dict incr dummy key1 1
set dummy [testProc $dummy]
puts [dict get $dummy]
```

or pass the *name* of the variable holding the dict and use [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.html) (Similar to how `dict incr` etc. works):

```
proc testProc {aDict} {
    upvar $aDict a
    # some statements ...
    dict incr a key2 1
}

set dummy [dict create]
dict incr dummy key1 1
testProc dummy
puts [dict get $dummy]
```